# Cannot have more than 0 builds in queue for the account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm newbie in AWS, with my free tier account I'm trying to build my nodeJS project with AWS CodeBuild but I get this error:

> - Build failed to start The build failed to start. The following error occured: Cannot have more than 0 builds in queue for the account

I followed the simple aws tutorial, leaving all default settings for let aws create all service, image etc for me. 
Also I stored source code in a AwsCodeCommit repository.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063206/errors-on-using-codebuild-for-first-time/54067490#54067490. You will need to contact AWS support.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, there was a security vulnerability in my account and AWS automatically raised a support ticket and suspended all resources that were linked to it. I had to fix it and then on chat with aws support they resumed my service.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a lot of answers around the web suggesting to call support, which is a great idea, but I was actually able to get around this on my own.

As the root user I went in and put in a current credit card. The one that was currently there was expired. I then deleted my CodeBuild project and create a new one. Now my builds work! It makes sense that AWS just needed a valid payment method before it allowed me to use premium services.

My solution may not work for you, but sure I hope it does!

Answer (score 1):

My error was `Project-level concurrent build limit cannot exceed the account-level concurrent build limit of 1` when I tried to increase the `Concurrent build limit` under checkbox `Restrict number of concurrent builds this project can start` in CodeBuild Project Configuration. I resolved it by **writing to support** to increase the limit. They increased it to 20 and it works now as expected. They increased it even though I'm on Basic plan on AWS if anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add new service role name and the concurrent build to 1. This worked

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is resolved at the moment. Any way I faced the same issue. In my case I had a "code build project" connecting to a GitHub repository. And then I added AWS Access Key and Secret hard coding the  buildspec.yml file. With this AWS identified it as an unauthorized login. So they added security restrictions to the resources while opening a support issue. In such a case you can look for the emails from AWS in which they explain the reason for this behavior and the steps to get this corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the **"Build failed to start Cannot have more than 0 builds in queue for the account"** issue, I reached out to AWS support, explaining the situation and the specific error message. I requested an increase in the service quota to allow for at least 1 build in the account-level queue. AWS support was able to assist with this it took 1 day for the necessary adjustments to resolve the problem. This approach effectively resolved the issue, allowing my builds.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhPYE.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).