# New account from Organization is not able to do any CodeBuild actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-organizations

The problem is, that I have created new Organization and accounts there on custom OU. I didn't apply any SCP or other kind of restrictions there. But still, when I try on child account run the CodeBuild job, got the error:

> "Build failed to start. The following error occurred: Cannot have more
> than 0 builds in queue for the account".

I even tried to put the own payment card on child account, and re-create build, but still no luck :(

Did anyone spot such an issue? How it can be resolved?

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600828/cannot-have-more-than-0-builds-in-queue-for-the-account

Comment: I already did the check of it, but unfortunatelly no luck

Comment: I am in the same situation, I ended by cutting a ticket to support and now I am waiting for that. Since this question was asked 1 year ago, I wonder if you can share what solution you found.